# How to fix a syntax error in Grub?

Tags: arch-linux, grub

I want to update my grub settings.

I get the following message

```
# grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-linux
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-linux.img
Found fallback initrd image(s) in /boot: initramfs-linux-fallback.img
Found Windows 10 on /dev/sda1
error: syntax error.
error: Incorrect command.
error: syntax error.
Syntax error at line 178
Syntax errors are detected in generated GRUB config file.
Ensure that there are no errors in /etc/default/grub
and /etc/grub.d/* files or please file a bug report with
/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new file attached.
```

[here is the pastbin of `/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new`](https://pastebin.com/rTaqU7sr)

I tried to look into the files in `/etc/grub.d/*` but was unsuccessful in debugging.

Comment: Update with the output of `cat /etc/grub.d/40_custom`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To aid you in future debugging, I documented your search for the error that I made.

The problem is in line 178.

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
 
 
 
if [ "${grub_platform}" == "pc" ]; then
fi                                            #<------that is line 178
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
```

So, the problem is clearly in `40_custom`.

About these files, it is said:

> These files should not be modified unless you are a GRUB expert and understand what the changes will do. Even then you should always keep a backup copy of the original, working grub.cfg file. The specific files, 40_custom and 41_custom are intended to be used to generate user modifications to the GRUB configuration. You should still be aware of the consequences of any changes you make to these files and maintain a backup of the original grub.cfg file.

So it is probably an addition that you made to this file.

Experienced shell scripters will already have spotted that

```
if [ "${grub_platform}" == "pc" ]; then 
    :
fi
```

will solve your syntax error. I explicitly state "syntax" error, because I do not know what your intentions were.

You will change this in `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` (the file you probably edited) and not in `grub.cfg`, but that should have been clear from the comment in that file:

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#
```

Comment: The `.cfg` is auto generated using a literal copy of  `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`. The part that I quoted from his pastebin is the content of `40_custom`. I quoted this part, because it is, as you said, essential.   (added the remark that this must be corrected in `40_custom` to my reply)

Comment: Right, this addition seems very good, I think this should be emphasized, for not leaving any room for anyone to edit into there.

Comment: Thank you so much. I this is new to me. I only sporadically work with `bash` scripts. This `if` condition is new to me. Because of your effort and explanation you for sure get the accepted answer badge.

Comment: Just as a follow up should I have seen it by myself?

Comment: If you do a lot of bash-scripting; this is evident. In `bash`, your if-then-fi cannot have an empty command part between the `then` and `fi`. By putting the ':' between them, you have a command (: is a shell built-in for true). Anyway, if you are unsure about your script, try running them stand-alone with lots of echos in it.